# Custom comparator to segregate even and odd giving TLE

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to implement the solution for this leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-array-by-parity/. (i.e. segregate even and odd elements in an array)

I wrote the below solution using custom comparator in C++:

```
bool custom_cmp(int &l, int &r){
    return l%2 == 0;
}

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortArrayByParity(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), custom_cmp);
        return nums;
    }
};
```

However, the above solution gives me TLE and is apparently taking more than O(n*logn) time.

Next, I changed the custom comparator in the above code as follows:

```
bool custom_cmp(int &l, int &r){
    return (l%2 < r%2);
}
```

The above solution works perfectly fine and is not giving me TLE. Both of the solutions seem to use the same sorting algorithm and the results of the two comparator class also seem the same.

Can you help me explain what is the difference between the above two implementations and why the second one works while the first one fails?

Comment: The posted answer is correct, your first compare function is not suitable for sorting. However, it can be used with the [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) algorithm. It will segregate the values and is likely faster than sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first comparator does not meet the requirements defined by [`Compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) since it doesn't take `r`'s value into account (i.e. it does not properly establish a "strict weak ordering").

For example, one requirement that the first comparator violates is:

> For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`

Which we can easily break with `custom_cmp(0, 0)`.

As an experiment I tried using the same comparator in [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hY6PWhMqa), and interestingly it actually ends up invoking Undefined Behavior because of the unsatisfied contract.